# Implement relational operator in string class c++

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading

I try to overload relational operator in my own `String` class. This how the class look like: I store the string inside `data` which is an array.

```
class MyString
{
public:

    //default constructor, create an empty string
    MyString() 
    {

    };

    //create a string containing n copies of c
    MyString(size_t n, char c) :data(new char[n]), data_length(n)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            data[i] = c;
        }
    };

    //create a string from a null-terminated array
    MyString(const char *cp):data(new char[std::strlen(cp)]), data_length(std::strlen(cp))
    {
        //std::copy(cp, cp + std::strlen(cp), data);
        std::copy(cp, cp + std::strlen(cp), stdext::checked_array_iterator<char*>(data, data_length));
    }

    //destructor
    ~MyString()
    {
        //free the array
        delete[] data;  
    };


    //relational operators
    bool operator==(const char* lhs, const char* rhs)
    {

    }

private:
    size_t data_length;
    char* data;
};
```

1. Compiler says that cant overload more than 2 args so I understand that `lhs` must be implicit like this:

   ```
   bool operator==(const char* rhs)
   {

   }
   ```

but, my problem is: 
Supposing that I compare two strings which sit inside a null-terminated array how can I compare them in something like a loop?

Comment: You cannot overload operators with strictly built-in types. This includes pointers. You may not redefine the meaning of comparing two pointers for equality.

Comment: But here I see that it can be oveloaded http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/

Comment: Each of those overloads has at least 1 class type argument.

Comment: [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) is a list of all the overloads you are going to need.

Comment: More explicitly, you cannot overload operators where _all_ of the operands are built-in types.

Comment: You say you want relational operators for your string class but you show code for relational operators for `const char *`. Did you mean to write `bool operator==(const MyString &lhs, const MyString &rhs)`?

Comment: @nwp cant I compare const char* args?

Comment: Sure you can compare `const char *`s. C++ already has a built in comparison function that does that (probably doesn't do what you want though). But that has nothing to do with `MyString`. What you might want to do is add a comparison function to compare `MyString`s to `const char *`s.

Comment: @axcelenator *Supposing that I compare two strings which sit inside a null-terminated array how can I compare them in something like a loop?* -- Then this has nothing to do with your string class, and you fall back to using 'C' functions, such as `strcmp`.

Comment: Alright I get it now, so if I declare for example `bool operator==(const MyString &lhs, const MyString &rhs)` I implement the function with `strcmp`?

Comment: @axcelenator -- *I implement the function with strcmp?* -- Your string class uses `data_length` to determine the string length, not a null terminator.   Thus using `strcmp` to compare `MyString` won't work if you truly are comparing `MyString` objects since `strcmp` will stop at the first null, not necessarily where `data_length` says is the end of the string.  You use `strcmp` to compare two null-terminated **C-style** strings.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But if I will terminate the `data` array ?

Comment: @axcelenator -- *But if I will terminate the data array ?* -- You *are* terminating the array.  The termination is determined by `data_length`.  Look at your constructor.  Better yet, write a `MyString::size()` or `length()` function -- what will you return?

Comment: You could do something like `bool operator==(const MyString &lhs, const MyString &rhs){ return lhs.data_length == rhs.data_length && std::memcmp(lhs.data, rhs.data, lhs.data_length) == 0; }`. You probably should use [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) instead to not have to rely on C functions.

Comment: @nwp Compiler says: `too many parameters for this operator function`

Comment: Add `friend` in front of it or use the member version `bool operator==(const MyString &other)` where you replace `lhs.` with `this->` and `rhs` with `other`.

Comment: @axcelenator -- The overloaded `==` function that has two arguments require it to be outside the class itself, not a class member (you can make it `friend` but still needs to be implemented outside the class).  You more than likely want to use the one argument `operator ==` function within the class.

Comment: Alright thank you all